# ValueLisenableBulder not updating in ListView [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, debugging, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, state-management

I'm working on a storie list
when the `create storie` button clicked i want add a new `StorieCard` to the list

[image: whether the create button new Storie card want to update on the ui]

here the problem is the `StorieCard` is added to the my `List` but the ui is not updating.

this is my List

```
ValueNotifier<List<Widget>> storieList = ValueNotifier([
  StorieCard(userhasStorie: false),
  StorieCard(),
]);
```

this is my `build` but here the `UI` is not `updating`

```
class Stories extends StatelessWidget {
  Stories({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      child: ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: storieList,
        builder: (BuildContext context, List<Widget> newList, Widget? child) {
          return ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
              return newList[index];
            },
            itemCount: newList.length,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the `Button Action`

```
createStorieAction() {
   
    storieList.value.add(StorieCard());
    print('new Value added to storie list');
  }
```

when i clicking the button the new card is adding to the list butting happening in the ui

Comment: You can check [this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29958) in order to find out why adding an item to the list does not notify the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For value notifiers, flutter compares the interval value using its `equals` method. Since you are passing a list object... when inserting or removing list items, the list itself would still equal to the same old list.

In simpler words, consider this short example:

```
final a = List();
final b = a;  // assign a and b to the same list
assert (a == b); // obviously true
a.add(1);
assert(b.first == 1);
assert (a == b); // still pointing to the same list
```

In the above example, both `a` and `b` are pointing to the same list, so adding an item isn't easily "noticeable" by the value notifier.

One way to solve it, is to reassign the list.

Using the above short example, instead of doing `a.add(1)`, you could do: `a = [...a, 1];`

Comment: it is showing me error while i try to do that . can you plz show this on the above code .it might be more helpfull

Comment: `storieList.value = [your new list]`